# How to remove duplicated browser from a drop down when choosing default browser?

Tags: macos, applications, google-chrome

**How to remove Chrome 54 from this list?** I don't use it and it's not installed.

However I do use Chrome 61 and it's visible in `Applications` - I want this one to stay as it is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found what was the "issue" with duplicated Google Chrome. Version 54 was installed via `brew cask install google-chrome` while the second one was installed in a traditional way.

After calling `brew cask uninstall --force google-chrome` and re-downloading the classic version, everything came back to normal.